How to quickly find a parametrized tuple in pytest.mark.parametrize related to a certain id
I have a long list of 20+ tuples in pytest.mark.parametrize and an equally long ids corresponding to each tuple. Without having to debug or run the test, how do you identify which tuple goes with which ID?
My method was to either use a debugger and get the tuple from the method by running the code or counting them down. I'm looking for a better way that might be more efficient. I'm using vscode if anyone has a plugin to share.

Why not use a dict (mapping ID to the tuple) and provide this_dict.values() to parametrize? Or even pass IDs to make test names shorter and use it inside the test to get the value from the dictionary?
